# Spring Reactor not working on handle operation while DB fetch

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm using spring reactor. The code below is :

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<SignUpResponse>> createSignUpForUser(SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {  
    return Mono.just(signUpRequest)                                                                                                        
            .map(sign -> {               
                  Mono<UserDetailsEntity> userDetailsEntityMono = userDetailsRepository.findByPhoneNumber(sign.getMobileNumber());
                  userDetailsEntityMono.handle((user, sink) -> {
                    if (user != null) {
                        sink.error(new RuntimeException("Phone number already registered"));
                    }
                });
                return functionUserDetails.apply(sign);
            })
            .flatMap(userDetailsRepository::save)
            .map(functionUser)
            .flatMap(userRepository::save)
            .map(usr -> ResponseEntity.ok(functionSignUpRes.apply(usr)))
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
            .log();
}
```

Here the **findByPhoneNumber(sign.getMobileNumber())** DB call is not working (the error is not throwing). The Rest of the operations are working and returning the response. *Am i doing anything wrongly* ? help me to fix this issue.

Comment: so if number is not in database is not working right ? and it return 404?

Comment: Hey if my answer help i would appreciate accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to rewrite your code a bit

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<SignUpResponse>> createSignUpForUser(SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {

        return userDetailsRepository.findByPhoneNumber(sign.getMobileNumber())
                .flatMap(__ -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Phone number already registered")))
                .switchIfEmpty(userDetailsRepository.save(functionUserDetails.apply(sign)))
                .map(functionUser)
                .flatMap(userRepository::save)
                .map(usr -> ResponseEntity.ok(functionSignUpRes.apply(usr)))
                .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
                .log()
                
        ;
    }
```

Idea is that if you find that number then it should error, if result is empty then you would need to insert it so we need to use switch if empty

Comment: Thanks @Vova Bilyachat i have changed a bit also to make it work.
**.switchIfEmpty(userDetailsRepository.save(functionUserDetails.apply(signUpRequest)))
                .map(ude -> functionUser.apply((UserDetailsEntity) ude))** Let me know if any change is needed.

Comment: @red perfect, my code was to direct you. If it helps i would appreciate +1 and accept the answer